# Logistic Maps Homework Help

Tags: logic, fixed-point-theorems

Consider the logistic map $G(x) = 4x(1-x)$. Let $q_0=0<q_1<q_2<q_3...<q_7$ be the eight points left fixed by $G^3$. Determine which are the two fixed points and which other points are grouped together into period-3 orbits. Hint: Remember that the fixed points are $0$ and $3/4$.

I'm able to answer a similar question for $G^2$, but I've got no idea how to answer this question for $G^3$. I know that by my calculations $G^2(x) =4[4x(1-x)][1-4x(1-x)]$ and $G^3(x)=4[4(4x(1-x))(1-4x(1-x)][1-4(4x(1-x))(1-x)].$ How can I use this equation to determine which are the fixed points and which other points are grouped together into period-3 orbits?

Comment: how do you do it for $G^2$? Why that same method doesn't work for your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solve:  $G^3(x)=4[4(4x(1-x))(1-4x(1-x)][1-4(4x(1-x))(1-x)] = x$ using Wolfram Alpha.

( Solve[64 (1 - x) x (1 - 4 (1 - x) x) (1 - 16 (1 - x) x (1 - 4 (1 - x) x)) == x, {x}] ) should work .

The two fixed points are $0$ and $\frac{3}{4} $ , There are in fact two three cycles
which you can find by iterating the other roots using $G(x)$ .

Comment: How do I use G(x) to find the 3 cycles?

Comment: Your answer should contain roots to good accuracy I suppose , but I get .95 --> .188 --> .611 --> .95 and .1169 --> .4131 --> 0.9698 by starting with any of these roots and iterating with $G$ .

Comment: Okay, I've figured out that much, but how can I determine if points are grouped together in orbit?

Comment: Oh, you can just keep track of the two cycles,  ( 1 -->2 -->3 --> 1) and  ( 4 -->5 -->6 --> 4) , two distinct orbits . Actually, you are looking at a limiting case, it will help you here to look at the logistic map with variable parameter  $ r x(1-x)$ . As r varies the pattern of orbits changes, you should look at the picture of this , I'm sure you can google it , if it isn't already on this site.